# What algorithm is this graph coding exercise?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra

I have a graph coding exercise that I don't know which algorithm to use. I will try to explain it as clearly as I can.

> The algorithm takes two input: a 2D matrix `matrix` and a positive integer `t`. `matrix[A][B] = C` means that the edge from A to B has weight C. C can be negative. There is no loop in this graph.  Let the first row be the starting point, and the last row be the ending point. The other rows between starting and ending points are named vertices 0, 1, 2...The positive integer `t` indicates time. Each time you travel between two vertices, t is deducted by the weight of that edge. For example, travelling from A to B updates the time left as `t = t - C`. When t is negative, the door is closed and you cannot exit. Travelling between negative weight edges increases t (because t = t - (-C) = t + C). When t is 0 and/or a positive number, the door is reopened, only then you can exit. Return the result as an array with indicates the most vertices you have travelled and which are they. Try to maximize the number of vertices you can travel. If there are multiple answers with the same size, return the set of the lowest vertex indicates by its name (if there are two answers: `answer = [0,1]` and `answer = [1,2]`, return only `[0,1]`). There is always at least one solution for every test case.

I have learned BFS, DFS, Djikstra, Ford-Fulkerson, some minimum spanning tree algorithms like Prim, Kruskal but I don't think any of them can be applied to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: as requested by Photon's comment I will clarify some other points:

- Given an 3x3 matrix, the vertices will be named like this:

```py
matrix = 
[
 [0,1,1], # Starting point
 [1,0,1], # Vertex 0
 [1,1,0]  # Ending point
]
```

- The time `t` will be no more than 999.
- The max matrix size will be 7x7. There is no time limit, but the better complexity the better.
- Going through an edge again requires you to "pay" the time again.
- You must reach the ending point in the end (and the door must be opened at that time in order to exit).
- It is not required to exit immediately when reaching the ending point for the first time.
- Any programming language is acceptable.

Sample solution:

```py
matrix = 
[
  [0, 2, 2, 2, -1],  # 0 = Start
  [9, 0, 2, 2, -1],  # 1 = Vertex 0
  [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],  # 2 = Vertex 1
  [9, 3, 2, 0, -1],  # 3 = Vertex 2
  [9, 3, 2, 2,  0],  # 4 = End
]
```

The path is: `Start -> End -> Vertex 1 -> End -> Vertex 2 -> End`, so the answer is `[1,2]`. 
So you move 5 times. Time changes after each move is:
Initial: 1 (door opens), first: 2, second: 0, third: 1, fourth: -1 (door closes), fifth: 0 (door reopens, you exit).

Comment: It looks like an error feedback, maybe ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

Comment: could you clarify further: what are the rows you mention? what are the limits on matrix size and time? after going to an edge will we need to pay again if we travel this edge again? Do we need to reach the exit or can we just end stuck on some node?
Ideally some simple example would help a lot in understanding your problem.

Comment: @Pierre I don't think it's Machine learning-related. Possibly I can think of Ford-Fulkerson, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It sounds like you want the longest path whose sum of weights is less than or equal to t. If this is the case then the problem is probably NP-Hard and there is probably no better solution than just checking every path and remembering the longest viable one you encountered. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem. It seems like longest path because instances of your problem could choose t so large that any path is allowed and thus your problem is at least as hard as longest path in the general case.

Comment: If the problem gives t so large that it allows any path, we can just return the whole vertices right? Although there is no constraint about t, but I think it should be as min as possible, else we can just return everything.

Comment: 'There is no loop in this graph' -- 'Going through an edge again requires you to "pay" the time again.' 

Comment: @StefanHaustein you seem to misunderstand between cycle and loop in graph. Loop means a node connects with itself.